# Generate scaffold for multiple namespaces using same migration and model on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use scaffold to generate multiple namespaces, but I would like to use the same model and same migration database for all. So I tried this:

```
rails g scaffold years title:string slug:string

rails g scaffold admin::years title:string slug:string --skip-model

rails g scaffold api::years title:string slug:string --skip-model --api
```

Then when I went to check the files, it generated all these files:

```
models/year.rb
models/api/year.rb
models/admin/year.rb 

migrate/_create_years.rb
migrate/_create_admin_years.rb
migrate/_create_api_years.rb
```

But I would like to have the controllers and views of admin and API using the same model:

```
models/year.rb
```

and also using the same table generated on:

```
migrate/_create_years.rb
```

What would be the correct scaffold commands to achieve that?

Comment: What you're trying to do falls outside of the scope of what scaffolds are supposed to achieve and it would be easier to just write the code right off the bat. The scaffolds are just for rapid prototyping typical CRUD MVCs for a resource.

Comment: If you really had to do this for example as part of gem the answer is to create your own generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `skip-model` option on the scaffold command, so that's why that didn't work. You could use the `--skip-migration` option to least suppress the migrations, but you'd still need to delete the models, test files, etc.

A way to get closer to what you want is to use `scaffold` for your base model and then use `rails generate scaffold_controller` for the other two:

```sh
% rails g scaffold years title:string slug:string
 <...>

% rails g scaffold_controller admin/year
 <...>

% r g scaffold_controller api/year --api                                         
create  app/controllers/api/years_controller.rb
invoke  jbuilder
invoke  resource_route
  route    namespace :api do
    resources :years
  end
invoke  test_unit
create    test/controllers/api/years_controller_test.rb
invoke  helper
create    app/helpers/api/years_helper.rb
invoke    test_unit
invoke  jbuilder
create    app/views/api/years
create    app/views/api/years/index.json.jbuilder
create    app/views/api/years/show.json.jbuilder
create    app/views/api/years/_api_year.json.jbuilder
```

Comment: That was a good tip and created the files in correct folders, but than i have to edit manually the controllers and views to make it work. I wonder if there is a way  or a gem to make that more simple, rsrs. but thanks a lot for the answer.